# React do not hit Django API on kubernetes

Tags: reactjs, django, kubernetes, django-rest-framework, axios

I have a django drf API and a react APP in a cluster kubernetes.

My API is not exposed (i cannot expose it because of security conditions).
React APP is exposed with an ingress.

React need to consume Django API (via axios). But it seems that axios requests are made by browsers so api service is unreachable.

Need someone already faced this issue?

Thanks in advance!
Gauthier

Comment: In you react app you need to include some backend code and from there, call your django api.

Comment: Can you give me more explanation please? It is not really clear for me

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/

Comment: Thanks but not exactly what I need. I want Django and React can communicate inside cluster directly

Comment: It's exactly what you need...you just need to read it 

Comment: So basically, what you want to do it to communicate your react app exposed with a load balancer service, with your node backend that is a cluster ip service....and you can't....you need to create a sort of middleware with express to communicate internally with your cluster ip service. That way, from you are now serving your react app from express and you are calling your express endpoints that are visible to your axios client, but express is comunicating internally with you cluster ip service. That is going to do the trick....and read and think, before discard information so easilly 

Answer (score 0):

Your Django API must be accessible from inside. Use some **Load Balancer service** like ELB in AWS or SLB in Aliyun to redirect your browser requests to your Django API service.

This way your Django API service could be exposed through **Nodeport service** or **inner ingress**.